# Why does the play store show "deactivate" instead of uninstall

Tags: google-play-store

I was reviewing the recent update changes for the Outlook app when I noticed that instead of the normal uninstall button, it says dectivate instead:

[image: screenshot of button showing deactivate]
<sup>Screenshot showing the button (click to enlarge)</sup>

I don't believe that this is a core app as its a Samsung phone (specifically the Core LTE).

Why is the play store showing deactivate instead of uninstall?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is probably because you have configured Outlook as a Device Administrator. This prevents you from uninstalling the app. If you wish to uninstall Outlook you will need to go to `Settings` > `Security` > `Device Administrators` and uncheck Outlook. This will then allow you to uninstall the app.

<sub>Steps taken from Nexus 5 so may differ slightly on other devices</sub>

Comment: Thanks for the info. I didn't even think of that. +1